# why when I tried to Turns GLTFs into JSX components using npx gltfjsx model.gltf. I got .jsx file instead of .js file?

Tags: gltf

I used npx gltfjsx model.gltf, I got the .jsx file instead of .js file. How should I fix it?

the .js file has much more informatio than the .jsx file. The .jsx file I got when I import to my react, it doest work.
this is the .jsx:
`<group {...props} dispose={null}> <group rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} scale={0}> <group rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}> <mesh geometry={nodes.defaultMaterial.geometry} material={materials.Material} scale={13.669} /> </group> </group> </group>`

the .js got more s:
`return ( <group {...props} dispose={null}> <PerspectiveCamera name="camera" fov={40} near={10} far={1000} position={[10, 0, 50]} />       <pointLight intensity={10} position={[100, 50, 100]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} /> <group position={[10, -5, 0]}> <mesh geometry={nodes.robot.geometry} material={materials.metal} /> <mesh geometry={nodes.rocket.geometry} material={materials.wood} /> </group> </group> ) }`